# Tab Item Selection Programmatically

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am trying to programmatically set tab selection for my `tabLayout`. I keep getting a `null pointer`.

```
 firebaseFirestore.collection("Categories")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, document.getString("title") + " => " + document.getData());
                                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(document.getString("title")));
                                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
                                tabLayout.getTabAt(5).select();
                                final CategoriesPagerAdapter categoriesPagerAdapter = new CategoriesPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
                                viewPager.setAdapter(categoriesPagerAdapter);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Why does `getTabAt(5).select` keep returning null?

Comment: Does your `TabLayout` always have six tabs at that point? Are you sure that's where you want that call in the first place? Are you sure you don't want it after the loop? Along with the `Adapter` and `ViewPager` lines?

Comment: i have 16 tabs which are fetched from my database as an arraylist.

Comment: You're doing that inside the `for` loop. Unless your `TabLayout` already has at least six tabs when `onComplete()` runs, that's going to return null the first time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to select a tab that hasn't been added to the `TabLayout`. You are calling this...

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(5).select();
```

after this...

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(document.getString("title")));
```

try moving the call to `select` out of the `for` loop.
Also, be aware that the documentation explicitly says the following about the `select` method...

> Select this tab. Only valid if the tab has been added to the action bar.

So, if the `TabLayout` hasn't been added to the action bar it will do nothing.

Another issue is that you are re-creating and setting the viewpager's adapter on every single iteration of the `for` loop.

My advice, please stop working on this app until you are sure what you are doing. You have more than one obvious bugs in the code snippet you posted